# Change div height with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, height

I need some scripting like the TYPO3 extension / module that runs on this site : http://nyati-safari.dk/index.php?id=125 (Scroll to: Detaljeret Dagsprogram (inkluderet)).

[image: Screenshot]

The div is shown with a pixelspecific height and when the arrow is clicked the div changes to contentspecific height also the arrow changes when the div toggles.

Comment: Seems like it's working to me...

Comment: Yes it works just fine, but i need some similar for another site (not TYPO3 site)

Comment: Have you tried something already? It's not so hard. Just attach a `click` handler to the arrow and adjust the height of the `<div>`

Comment: Could you show an example, i'm newbie :(

Comment: the dropdown background looks like a MacOS lion.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var div = $('#div');

$('#arrow').click(function () {
    if (div.height() == 100) {
        autoHeight = div.css('height', 'auto').height();
        div.height(100).animate({
            height: autoHeight
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $('#div').animate({
            height: '100'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG8ug/5/

Can even do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG8ug/6/ where the 'hidden' div is small on page load but when viewed and returned it is bigger. Might be useful to help users distinguish what has already been viewed. Could even do it the other way around too so the div takes up even less space when it has been viewed.

Comment: Just change 100 to be whatever you want the fixed height to be.

Comment: Added a nice text fade-out to show that some text is hidden. See the jsFiddle. :D

Comment: Thx alot. Ill try to implement ASAP. Can you show me how to implement some button, as described ?

Comment: The clickable button is the `#arrow` div. Just style it how you like. :)

Comment: I need the arrow to have 2 different stages. 1) When the div has a small height and 2) When the div is at full height. Maybe my question is simple. But i dont know how to do it. /Greetings SM4000